# Copy from one memory to another skipping constant bytes in C

Tags: c, memory

I am working on embedded system application. I want to copy from source to destination, skipping constant number of bytes. For example: `source[6] = {0,1,2,3,4,5}` and I want destination to be {0,2,4} skipping one byte. Unfortunately `memcpy` could not fulfilled my requirement. How can I achieve this in 'C' without using loop as I have large data to process and using loop experiences time overhead.

My current implementation is something like this which takes upto 5-6 milli-seconds for 1500 bytes to copy:

```
unsigned int len_actual = 1500; 
/* Fill in the SPI DMA buffer. */
 while (len_actual-- != 0) 
{
*(tgt_handle->spi_tx_buff ++) = ((*write_irp->buffer ++)) | (2 << 16) | DSPI_PUSHR_CONT; 
}
```

Comment: X-Y problem. Why do you need this?

Comment: Even `memcpy` uses a loop to copy the data. It can't be done without a loop.

Comment: I am using embedded device which is running at low frequency of 150 MHz, loop is taking some milli seconds if I process more than 1000 bytes which is not affordable in my case.

Comment: You would have to write your own copy function that allows you to skip bytes.

Comment: Make a loop and manually unroll each iteration for each copy you need.

Comment: if you alread coded a looping function and its too slow post that code here or on codereview.stackexchange.com so people can see if it can be speeded up

Comment: @pm100 I have posted code, kindly let me know if it can be optimized.

Comment: Can’t offer specific optimizations without knowing the architecture, but the simplest approach would be to increment the source pointer by 2 and the destination pointer by 1, since you’re already incrementing both. Your CPU might have a base+index addressing mode that can bit-shift the index.

Comment: another speedup is to work how memcpy is usually implemented. It reads a 32bit int and writes a 32bit int. Ie in chunks of 4 bytes. By bit shifting and juggling the 4 byte block you could probably do somehting similar

Answer (score 0):

You could write a "cherry picker" function

```
void * memcpk(void * destination, const void * source, 
              size_t num, size_t size
              int (*test)(const void * item));
```

which copies at most `num` "objects", each having size `size` from 
`source` to `destination`. Only the objects that satisfy the test are copied.
Then with

```
int oddp(const void * intptr) { return (*((int *)intptr))%2; }
int evenp(const void * intptr) { return !oddp(intptr); }
```

you could do

```
 int destination[6];
 memcpk(destination, source, 6, sizeof(int), evenp);
```

.

Comment: considering the OP concern with speed this seems like the wrong choice. Hard coding for every other byte seems better

Comment: OOPS! I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all CPUs have caches; which means that (e.g.) when you modify one byte the CPU fetches an entire cache line from RAM, modifies the byte in the cache, then writes the entire cache line back to RAM. By skipping small pieces you add overhead (more instructions for CPU to care about) and won't reduce the amount of data transfered between cache and RAM.

Also, typically `memcpy()` is optimised to copy larger pieces. For example, if you copy an array of bytes but the CPU is capable of copying 32-bits (4 bytes) at once, then `memcpy()` will probably do the majority of the copying as a loop with 4 bytes per iteration (to reduce the number of reads and writes and reduce the number of loop iterations).

In other words; code to avoid copying specific bytes will make it significantly slower than `mempcy()` for multiple reasons.

To avoid that, you really want to separate the data that needs to be copied from the data that doesn't - e.g. put everything that doesn't need to be copied at the end of the array and only copy the first part of the array (so that it remains "copy a contiguous area of bytes").

If you can't do that the next alternative to consider would be masking. For example, if you have an array of bytes where some bytes shouldn't be copied, then you'd also have an array of "mask bytes" and do something like `dest[i] = (dest[i] & mask[i]) | (src[i] & ~mask[i]);` in a loop. This sounds horrible (and is horrible) until you optimise it by operating on larger pieces - e.g. if the CPU can copy 32-bit pieces, masking allows you to do 4 bytes per iteration by pretending all of the arrays are arrays of `uint32_t`). Note that for this technique wider is better - e.g. if the CPU supports operations on 256-bit pieces (AVX on 80x86) you'd be able to do 32 bytes per iteration of the loop. It also helps if you can make guarantees about the size and alignment (e.g. if the CPU can operate on 32 bits/4 bytes at a time, ensure that the size of the arrays is always a multiple of 4 bytes and that the arrays are always 4-byte aligned; even if it means adding unused padding at the end).

Also note that depending on which CPU it actually is, there might be special support in the instruction set. For one example, modern 80x86 CPUs (that support SSE2) have a `maskmovdqu` instruction that is designed specifically for selectively writing some bytes but not others. In that case, you'd need to resort to instrinsics or inline assembly because "pure C" has no support for this type of thing (beyond bitwise operators).

Comment: Thanks alot, gonna try your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Having overlooked your speed requirements:
You may try to find a way which solves the problem without copying at all.

Some ideas here:

If you want to iterate the `destination` array you could define
kind of a "picky iterator" for `source` that advances to the next number you allow: Instead of `iter++` do `iter = advance_source(iter)`

If you want to search the `destination` array then wrap a function around `bsearch()` that searches `source` and inspects the result. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your processor memory width, and number of internal registers, you might be able to speed this up by using shift operations.

You need to know if your processor is big-endian or little-endian.

Lets say you have a 32 bit processor and bus, and at least 4 spare registers that the compiler can use for optimisation. This means you can read or write 4 bytes in the same target word, having read 2 source words. Note that you are reading the bytes you are going to discard.

You can also improve the speed by making sure that everything is word aligned, and ignoring the gaps between the buffers, so not having to worry about the odd counts of bytes.

So, for little-endian:

```
inline unsigned long CopyEven(unsigned long a, unsigned long b)
{
  long c = a & 0xff;
  c |= (a>>8) & 0xff00;
  c |= (b<<16) & 0xff0000;
  c |= (b<<8) &0xff000000;
  return c;
}

unsigned long* d = (unsigned long*)dest;
unsigned long* s = (unsigned long*)source;
for (int count =0; count <sourceLenBytes; count+=8)
{
   *d = CopyEven(s[0], s[1]);
   d++;
   s+=2;
}
```